# Python FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
def main():
    file = open('Lab09/data.dat', 'r')
```

No matter where I put data.dat or no matter how many times I retype the code so that it is an absolute path I get the same error code. I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

I was trying to get the code to access the file so that it could use the data stored in the file. I was expecting it to work but no matter what I can not get it to work.

Comment: What OS are you using? What happens if you use the full absolute path?

Comment: How are you running your code? From the command line? From an IDE (e.g. VSCode)? Relative file paths in Python are relative to the "current working directory", which is not always the same as the location of the script you're running.